# Limit number of "Add Block" in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Is it possible to limit the number of times you can "Add Block" in Wordpress 5+.

Comment: Should be possible. You could hide inserters in the backend and hook into the correct place where blocks are created to count the number of already existing blocks. check wp.data